# understanding how "button_to" works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In this code:

```
<

    % @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="entry">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <p><%= sanitize(product.description) %></p>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
    <!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
          <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product),
            remote: true %>
    <!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

At the bottom where we have button_to method with the params passed to it:

```
    <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product),
        remote: true %>
```

Looking at the code, here is my understanding of what is going on, Did I understand it correctly or I have missed something?

> In that code we are creating a button with text of "Add to Cart" and then we are
>   passing the product_id of the prodcut varaible to it, which is coming
>   from that for-each loop at the top and telling it go to link_items page with a
>   POST method for a product with ID of product_id .

**Another question:** in the lines_items_path could we just pass product.product_id ? or that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is an example from the [Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/097669400X) book. I read it long time ago... if I remember it right, there are `products`, `orders` and `line_items`.

if you call `rake routes` you will se that `line_items_path`, as POST, is the route for the`create` action in the `line_items_controller`. More details: [CRUD verbs and actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

So, you are passing the `product_id` to the create action, where you should have something like:

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
...
end
```

Comment: Yes that book.  Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I just understood your another question . The answer is : The code assigns the value of `product.id` to the symbol `product_id` . The symbol `product_id` is about to be used on the next step (probably for creating an association , in which the value of `product_id` is going to be a key) . Your question "why just `product` , but not `product.id` " will be reasonable one . The answer is in Rails framework's convention - if you'd like to use object's ID you just omit the `.id` part and Rails makes a guess correctly.

You cannot pass `product.product_id` , because the model Product does not have `product_id` method or property (which one you prefer) . It has `.id` .

Please , clarify the first part of your question .

EDIT (first part of the question- step by step)

`@products.each do |product|` - the loop iterates trough an array of objects (@products is array of objects , made up in the controller's action like this : `@products= Product.all` or similar ) . On every step the code inside `do  ..  end` operates on the local variable `product` . This is an object , which corresponds to one row of the database , thus it has "properties" (corresponding to columns) like product.id , product.name etc.

Then you create as many buttons as the count of the extracted db rows .

The information about which button is pressed , is carried by the new variable (in this case in form of a symbol - a special Ruby term , which deserves research :) ) So , you assign the value of product.id to it , like this : `product_id: product.id` . Summary : you made up the local variable `product_id` . The old style of this code : `:product_id => product` is more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks, I am reading your answer to my second question to understand it. I have also updated the first part of the question.